# Eventos em botões

Tags: android

Como faço para colocar evento nos **botões** para chamar outra tela no Android? Estou usando o **Intent**, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e mostre o código que você tentou, por favor.

Comment: Seja um pouco mais claro, sua dúvida está na parte de criar um evento ou especificamente em como chamar outra tela?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suponha que você tem duas `Activities`, a `AtividadeA` e a `AtividadeB`, e que a `AtividadeA` vai ter um botão que vai chamar a `AtividadeB`.

Funciona assim:

1) No layout da sua primeira activity (que possivelmente tem o nome de `activity_main.xml`) você inclui um botão (`Button`) com um `id`...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/meuBotao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clique em mim"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Na sua AtividadeA você declara um botão...

```
private Button botao;
```

3) No método `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` você inicializa o botão e associa a ele um `View.OnClickListener`...

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
botao = (Button)findViewById(R.id.meuBotao);
botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AtividadeA.this, AtividadeB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

4) Não se esqueça de declarar as duas activities no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>

    ...

    <activity android:name="AtividadeA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="AtividadeB" />

    ...

</application>
```

Entendeu? Qualquer dúvida é só comentar. Se estiver satisfeito com a resposta, pode aceitá-la clicando no ícone à esquerda da mesma.